# What does this mean....TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'names.slice')?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can someone please help me out with this error, this occurs when I type `npm start` and press `I` to open my iOS stimulator...
This is my code, just for your reference (Thanks in advance!):

**This is what I see in my terminal:**

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'names.slice')

```
This error is located at:
    in ModuleSelect (at SceneView.tsx:122)
    in StaticContainer
    in StaticContainer (at SceneView.tsx:115)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at SceneView.tsx:114)
    in SceneView (at useDescriptors.tsx:153)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:245)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardContainer.tsx:244)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at CardSheet.tsx:33)
    in ForwardRef(CardSheet) (at Card.tsx:573)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:555)
    in PanGestureHandler (at GestureHandlerNative.tsx:13)
    in PanGestureHandler (at Card.tsx:549)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:165)
    in AnimatedComponent (at createAnimatedComponent.js:215)
    in ForwardRef(AnimatedComponentWrapper) (at Card.tsx:544)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Card.tsx:538)
    in Card (at CardContainer.tsx:206)
    in CardContainer (at CardStack.tsx:619)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:84)
    in MaybeScreen (at CardStack.tsx:612)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at Screens.tsx:54)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (at CardStack.tsx:494)
    in CardStack (at StackView.tsx:462)
    in KeyboardManager (at StackView.tsx:458)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaContext.tsx:74)
    in SafeAreaProvider (at SafeAreaProviderCompat.tsx:42)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (at StackView.tsx:455)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at StackView.tsx:454)
    in StackView (at createStackNavigator.tsx:87)
    in StackNavigator (at AppNavigator.js:25)
    in AppNavigator (at AppContainer.js:35)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (at BaseNavigationContainer.tsx:409)
    in ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer) (at NavigationContainer.tsx:91)
    in ThemeProvider (at NavigationContainer.tsx:90)
    in ForwardRef(NavigationContainer) (at AppContainer.js:34)
    in AppContainer (at App.js:13)
    in Provider (at App.js:11)
    in App (created by ExpoRoot)
    in ExpoRoot (at renderApplication.js:45)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:106)
    in DevAppContainer (at AppContainer.js:121)
    in RCTView (at View.js:34)
    in View (at AppContainer.js:132)
    in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:39)
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
  Image,
  Fragment,
} from "react-native";

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import EStyleSheet from "react-native-extended-stylesheet";
import CustomText from "../components/CustomText";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import { setModule, loadCurrentScenario } from "../store/game";

//thse are needed for screen layout
import ModuleButton from "../components/ModuleButton";
import { AvatarBase } from "../components/avatar/AvatarBase";

import SettingsStatusBar from "../components/SettingsStatusBar";
import Moduledrop from "../components/Moduledrop";
import CustomButton from "../components/CustomButton";

// from home screen
import { loadProgress, getCurrentmodule, getdModules } from "../store/game";
import { loadPoints } from "../store/results";
import { loadSettings } from "../store/settings";
import { sendUserAnalytics } from "../store/statistics";
import colors from "../config/colors";

function ModuleSelect() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const module = useSelector((state) => state.entities.game.currentModule);
  const scenarios = useSelector((state) => state.entities.game.currentScenario);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [moduledisplay, setmoduledisplay] = useState(0);

  //needed for drawing the module buttons
  const completedmodules = useSelector(
    (state) => state.entities.game.completedmodules
  );
  const modules = useSelector((state) => state.entities.game.distinctmodules);
  const names = useSelector((state) => state.entities.game.distinctnames);

  // let current_index = useSelector((state) => state.entities.game.current_index);

  const [current_index, setcurrent_index] = useState(0);
  let dnames = names.slice(current_index, current_index + 4);
  let dmodules = modules.slice(current_index, current_index + 4);

  // On navigation via navigation.navigate()
  useEffect(() => {
    const event = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      dispatch(loadProgress());
      dispatch(loadPoints());
      dispatch(sendUserAnalytics());
    });
    return event;
  }, [navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // action on update of movies
  }, [current_index]);

  const run = (id) => {
    dispatch(setModule(id));

    navigation.navigate("Modulelaunch", { displayedmodule: id });
  };

  const buttonpressup = () => {
    current_index + 4 > modules.length
      ? null
      : setcurrent_index(current_index + 1);
  };

  const buttonpressdown = () => {
    current_index + 4 == 4 ? null : setcurrent_index(current_index - 1);

    console.log(current_index);
  };

  const play = () => {
    navigation.navigate("testscreen");
  };

  const back = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Home");
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <SettingsStatusBar
        title={"Module Selection"}
        leftIcon={"chevron-left"}
        leftOnPress={() => navigation.navigate("Home")}
      />
      <View style={styles.toptext}>
        <CustomText style={styles.levelTextop}> Beginner </CustomText>
      </View>

      <TouchableOpacity
        style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
        onPress={() => buttonpressdown()}
      >
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/images/Entrypoints/doublearrowup.png")}
          style={styles.reallytinyLogo}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      <View style={styles.modulecontainer}>
        {dmodules.map((button) => (
          <ModuleButton
            ey={button}
            scenarioname={dnames[dmodules.indexOf(button)]}
            level={
              completedmodules.includes(dmodules[dmodules.indexOf(button)])
                ? "Completed"
                : "beginner"
            }
            id={button}
            left={(dmodules.indexOf(button) + 1) % 2 == 0 ? 50 : 5}
            top={
              dmodules.indexOf(button) == 0
                ? 25
                : dmodules.indexOf(button) * 150 + 25
            }
            op={() => run(button)}
            //op={() => handleplay(button)}
            completed={completedmodules.includes(button) ? 1 : 0}
          />
        ))}

        {dmodules.length > 1 ? (
          <View>
            <Moduledrop top={125} left={75} />
            <Moduledrop top={145} left={85} />
            <Moduledrop top={165} left={75} />
          </View>
        ) : null}

        {dmodules.length > 2 ? (
          <View>
            <Moduledrop top={255} left={55} />
            <Moduledrop top={280} left={45} />
            <Moduledrop top={315} left={45} />
          </View>
        ) : null}

        {dmodules.length > 3 ? (
          <View>
            <Moduledrop top={415} left={75} />
            <Moduledrop top={440} left={85} />
            <Moduledrop top={465} left={75} />
          </View>
        ) : null}

        <View style={styles.avatarContainer}>
          <AvatarBase style={styles.avatar} />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}
          onPress={() => buttonpressup()}
        >
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/images/Entrypoints/doublearrowdown.png")}
            style={styles.reallytinyLogo}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {/* <CustomButton
          style={{ backgroundColor: colors.VPNG_mauve }}
          title="Play"
          onPress={() => play()}
        /> */}

        <CustomButton
          style={{ backgroundColor: colors.VPNG_mauve }}
          title="Back"
          onPress={() => play("testscreen")}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = EStyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  modulecontainer: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    // top: 20,
    width: 200,

    //  borderWidth:1,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    top: -50,
    flex: 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    // paddingBottom: "25rem",
  },
  avatarContainer: {
    flex: 1.1,
    height: Dimensions.get("window").height / 1.4,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignContent: "center",
    elevation: -1,
    zIndex: -1,
    left: 225,
  },
  levelTextop: {
    fontFamily: "Raleway_700Bold",
    color: colors.VPNG_lightgrey,

    paddingLeft: 10,
    fontSize: "24rem",
  },
  toptext: {
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",

    width: "100%",
    height: 65,
  },
  reallytinyLogo: {
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
  },
});

export default ModuleSelect;
```

This is my entities.js file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import authReducer from './auth';
import usersReducer from './users';
import gameReducer from './game';
import resultsReducer from './results';
import settingsReducer from './settings';
import avatarReducer from './avatar';
import statisticsReducer from './statistics';

export default combineReducers({
    auth: authReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
    game: gameReducer,
    results: resultsReducer,
    settings: settingsReducer,
    avatar: avatarReducer,
    statistics: statisticsReducer
});
```

and this is my reducer.js file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import entitiesReducer from './entities';

export default combineReducers({
    entities: entitiesReducer
});
```

Comment: What is the value of `state.entities.game.distinctnames`? Can we see your reducers and how you combine them and form your redux state tree?

Comment: Yeah I have them in a separate js file, called entities....I edited my original post with the details.

Comment: What is the initial value of distinctnames in your gameReducer? if distinctnames is not defined then the names.slice() function will fail.

Comment: @Amruta Yes its currently defined like this: currentScenario: [],
  distinctmodules: [],
  distinctnames: [],

Comment: is that correct?